# Rename "Community"

Tags: discussion, community-user

The name of the user [Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is misleading: it's a bot and not a community of human beings, see the [explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community):

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>   I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>   I do things like ...

You might argue, my nick as well were misleading, 'cause no cookie I am. Yeah, but people know that I'm a real person, whoever. But the user "Community" with the rank of a moderator is something completely different and, being a bot, not connected to any connotation of the word "community".

I understand that the purpose is to gather sympathy, but why do we need marketing blabla here?

If the age of more or less autonomous bots has started, let's separate them clearly, from the beginning.

What about "TeX.se-Bot"?

Comment: I doubt this can change on tex.sx you'd have to raise it as a network change suggestion on meta.se

Comment: I myself don't like the name 'bot' and would opt for something like Automatic Moderation System. Whatever the name, consider also that the users' profile is not necessarily supposed to be read and pretending that an aforethought algorithm is a community, given the extemporary and unplanned nature of any community, is simply "unfair".

Answer (score 4):

Please remember that he is not exactly a bot. His competences are much more than actively doing something. Basically when the system needs to put a name to an action that has no name associated, it's this user that gets the action.

As for "bots": the name is ridiculous, and certainly below the level of professionalism that StackExchange aims at.

Comment: Why do you find “bot” ridiculous?  It’s a well-established term for exactly this: on a site where most users are human, a “bot” is a user identity that’s run from a script, set up to perform certain automated actions.  In any case, your answer doesn’t address the main question: the current name “community” is highly misleading, so shouldn’t we consider suggesting SE change that?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Note that tohecz is Czech and knows the precise origin of the term “robot”: a [drama by Karel Čapek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.U.R.)

Comment: Hah — indeed, yes.  But the current meaning, not the etymology, is surely what’s most relevant here!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine The word "bot" gives (at least to me) a strong feeling that "there's a computer that does a lot of stuff here". While this is true, it is clearly against the idea that the site is community-driven. But it may be just my feeling...

Comment: Community is actually a she: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/226928